# Output of HTML file not displaying image from C generated code

Tags: html, c, svg

So i have written a C program that outputs an HTML file which is supposed to print out 1000 SVG circles, rectangles and ellipses. When i run the html file in a browser it dones't print any of the shapes out. Heres what part of the code looks like (the beginning and end since it's a thousand lines)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSC 111 Fall 2015 -  Assignment 5 Part 2</title>
</head>
<body>
CSC 111 Art: <br /><svg width="800px" height="800px">
<g transform="translate(0 800)">
<g transform="scale(1 -1)">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="800" style="fill: none; stroke-width:     5; stroke:rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity:1.0;" />
<circle cx="63" cy="373" r="58" style="fill:rgb(170,190,91); fill-    opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="265" y="271" width="242" height="325" style="fill:rgb(90,23,196); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="356" y="179" width="42" height="314" style="fill:rgb(91,127,53); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<circle cx="26" cy="327" r="79" style="fill:rgb(151,136,102); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="202" y="280" width="127" height="398" style="fill:rgb(85,47,254); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<circle cx="298" cy="347" r="38" style="fill:rgb(33,95,51); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<circle cx="112" cy="266" r="19" style="fill:rgb(106,251,120); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="275" y="275" width="140" height="37" style="fill:rgb(187,37,21); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<circle cx="395" cy="11" r="93" style="fill:rgb(139,247,93); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="226" y="93" width="102" height="204" style="fill:rgb(140,222,148); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<circle cx="9" cy="118" r="72" style="fill:rgb(232,14,183); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="242" y="148" width="140" height="254" style="fill:rgb(167,132,206); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
<rect x="375" y="397" width="138" height="295" style="fill:rgb(179,175,20); fill-opacity:0.0"/>
</g></g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone point out issues with the code that would make it not run in the browser?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the 'c' language.  Suggest remove the 'c' tag

Comment: this line:  `fill-    opacity:0.0` will probably fail due to the embedded spaces in a keyword

Comment: depending on the browser and your overall settings, most of the counts may translate to bytes rather than pixels, which would put most of the graphics off the visible screen.

Comment: the use of `fill-opacity:0.0` in each object parameters makes the object invisible.  You might try:`fill-opacity:.5` in each object parameters as a starting point for correcting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you've posted runs just fine in a browser but I see two problems straight up.

---

First the color choice, though this *may* not be a problem at all depending on your browser color scheme.

If your browser has a background color of white as mine does, you'll never see objects specified with `rgb(255,255,255)`, simply because they'll be rendered as white-on-white.

---

Second (and this is the *real* problem), you'll never see objects with `fill-opacity:0.0` since they're perfectly transparent (effectively invisible).

If you just want solid non-transparent shapes, you should use `1.0` though, of course, you can choose values *between* `0` and `1` for varying levels of opacity.

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out as you posted this! Really appreciate it!